# EmberJS + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I've been really struggling getting a simple scenario running with EmberJS and Rails.

Here's what I have (combined JS):

```
App = Ember.Application.create
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true

App.Post = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  description: DS.attr 'string'

App.StreamRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set 'posts', model
  model: -> @store.find('post')

App.Router.map ->
  @.route 'stream', path: '/'
```

Here's the template content:

```
{{#each posts}}
  {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

Here's the `/posts` JSON for `Post.all` (perhaps this is wrong?):

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "posts": {
        "created_at": "2013-08-15T23:48:54+01:00",
        "description": "A few months ago I helped develop these posters for research that our UX team had gathered to create personas for our customers to show who they are and who actually uses our product.",
        "id": 7,
        "likes_count": 1,
        "slug": "16ErQ",
        "thumb": {
          "url": "\/posts\/1\/16ErQ\/man.png",
          "medium": {
            "url": "\/posts\/1\/16ErQ\/medium_man.png"
          }
        },
        "title": "Persona Project",
        "updated_at": "2013-08-15T23:48:54+01:00",
        "user_id": 1,
        "views_count": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "posts": {
        "created_at": "2013-08-16T15:47:03+01:00",
        "description": "Just a little something.",
        "id": 8,
        "likes_count": 0,
        "slug": "VYIvn",
        "thumb": {
          "url": "\/posts\/2\/VYIvn\/face.jpg",
          "medium": {
            "url": "\/posts\/2\/VYIvn\/medium_face.jpg"
          }
        },
        "title": "Face",
        "updated_at": "2013-08-16T15:47:03+01:00",
        "user_id": 2,
        "views_count": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "posts": {
        "created_at": "2013-08-16T17:03:10+01:00",
        "description": "Some people say, he's still running.",
        "id": 9,
        "likes_count": 2,
        "slug": "hQBnt",
        "thumb": {
          "url": "\/posts\/1\/hQBnt\/run.jpg",
          "medium": {
            "url": "\/posts\/1\/hQBnt\/medium_run.jpg"
          }
        },
        "title": "Run, Forest, run.",
        "updated_at": "2013-08-23T23:44:19+01:00",
        "user_id": 1,
        "views_count": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought this would be fine, but it doesn't quite work, when I run it, I get 3 post results (which is how many there are) but the columns all contain null values: http://c.daryl.im/RTzO

As you can see, I also have that error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON looks wrong. It should be something like this:

```
{
   "posts":[
      {
         "created_at":"2013-08-15T23:48:54+01:00",
         "description":"A few months ago I helped develop these posters for research that our UX team had gathered to create personas for our customers to show who they are and who actually uses our product.",
         "id":7,
         "likes_count":1,
         "slug":"16ErQ",
         "thumb":{
            "url":"/posts/1/16ErQ/man.png",
            "medium":{
               "url":"/posts/1/16ErQ/medium_man.png"
            }
          },
          "title":"Persona Project",
          "updated_at":"2013-08-15T23:48:54+01:00",
          "user_id":1,
          "views_count":0
      },
...
]}
```

Basically you have nested `posts` and need to remove one layer.

Comment: Any reason why it would do that?

Comment: How about your serializer?

Comment: You're correct. I needed a serializer! This did it: http://pste.co/p/mltjdnzd3myD

Comment: Try using [ActiveModel Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). It works nicely with `DS.ActiveModelSerializer` in the latest builds.